# When will invited persons show up?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In Animal Crossing: New Horizon, me and my two daughters live on an island. I invited one person to move to the island and my daughter invited two, but nothing has happened. Did I mess it up by asking one myself and didn't give my daughter all three? Every time we go to an island there is nobody there now. I don't know how to get to the next stage.

Comment: Can you clarify who you are asking, and also how new your island is, and how many other villagers live on your island? Are you using Amiibos to invite villagers to visit your island, or another method,?

Comment: I know that's a lot of detail, but each of those aspects can affect whether or not different visitors can come to your island, all for different reasons. Without knowing this we can't pinpoint the cause of the problem